# Add active state to simple jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I've got this simple accordion jQuery script that's almost there with what I need it for, but I'm struggling with one last thing. The animated bits work fine - i.e. if the corresponding content block is closed, it slides open, and vice versa.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
$('.accordion-heading').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp(300);
    $('.accordion-heading.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I want to have an 'active' class on the heading, but I need it to be removed if the same element is clicked twice. At the moment, everything works fine if a non-active heading is clicked. If an already-active heading is clicked again, however, the content block collapses correctly but the heading retains its 'active' class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the `.active` class from elements that aren't the current element (you can use the same `$.not()` method you are currently on another element), then `$.toggleClass()` the `.active` class on the clicked element.

```js
$('.accordion-heading').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp(300);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.accordion-heading').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-heading">heading</div>
  <div class="accordion-content">body</div>
  <div class="accordion-heading">heading</div>
  <div class="accordion-content">body</div>
  <div class="accordion-heading">heading</div>
  <div class="accordion-content">body</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Adding the class and removing the class I suggest using `.toggleClass()` this way if the element has the class it will remove it and if it doesn't it will add it.  If you want to have one of the accordions open manually give it the active class, and let your JS do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'toggleClass()' but I find its better to be more specific by checking if the item that was clicked has the class active. This way you can branch out and do other functions depending on the state:

```js
$('.accordion-heading').click(function(){

    var theHeading = $(this);
    var theContent = theHeading.next();
    var slideTimer = 300;

    if(theHeading.hasClass('active')) {
        $('.accordion-heading.active').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(slideTimer);
        theContent.slideDown(slideTimer);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
        theContent.slideUp(slideTimer);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }

});
```